# Are alphabetic cell references in org-table spreadsheet valid?

Tags: org-table, spreadsheet, column-references, alphabetic

I have this formula in one of my org-tables:

`#+TBLFM: A&='(concat "(vhtd/filegroups-init-group" " " (rc-dq C&) " " (rc-dq B&) " " (rc-dq D&) ")")`

and for some reason it doesn't work, but it seemed to work in the past.

After converting it to

`#+TBLFM: $1='(concat "(vhtd/filegroups-init-group" " " (rc-dq $3) " " (rc-dq $2) " " (rc-dq $4) ")")`

it works fine.

It seems strange to me, because the alphabetic references have been there as far as I can remember, unless some special mode is required to activate them, or some other text transformation change them accidentally.

Comment: The doc says `you may reference fields with a letter/number
combination like ‘B3’, meaning the second field in the third row`. So the letter is the column and the number is the row. But you seem to be using ampersands (`&`) instead of numbers. I've always used the `@n$m` notation, so I'm just going by what the documentation says.